# How to create circle on current location in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

I am working on flutter project.On which I have to draw one circle on my current location on google map.Does any one have idea.

**I want like this in flutter**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason to draw that circle? Is it to indicate the margin-of-error/accuracy of the current location (which is the current design of popular Map/Navigation apps)?

Comment: I want to set  radius around my current location with different colour.

Comment: I mean any rationale to have radius around your current location? Is it to indicate different radius (1 mile, 5 miles), is it only for aesthetic reason, etc?

Comment: It is only for aesthetic reason on my selected radius whatever I assign on it.All specific location should show me ,like restaurant ,hospital etc etc on selected circle radius.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This functionality is now available in the google_maps_flutter package:

https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Circle-class.html

Partial example:

```
Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([Circle(
    circleId: CircleId(id),
    center: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    radius: 4000,
)]);

GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    myLocationEnabled: true,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
    initialCameraPosition: initialMapLocation,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller.complete(controller);
    },
    onCameraMove: null,
    circles: circles,
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I will check it and revert back

Comment: The link you posted isn't working ... also how did you get circle ID. A detail answer is what needed !!!

Comment: @AliYarKhan     final circleId = CircleId('circle_id_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
I'm using this.

Comment: I have to redraw circle on map with different radius. Can you let me know how that possible? because onmapcreated method will call one time only.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya do u have a solution for updating circles?

Comment: @AliYarKhan You can use any random but unique string also. Example circleId: CircleId('myuniquecircleid')

Answer (score 14):

If you use [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map) plugin, then you can draw radius circle easily. Here is the code.

```
FlutterMap(
    options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 16.0
    ),
    layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "map url",
            additionalOptions:  {
            "accessToken" : "xxx",
            "id" : "map id"
            }
        ), 
        MarkerLayerOptions(
            markers: Marker( //marker
                width: 25.0,
                height: 25.0,
                point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                        iconSize: 25.0,
                        color: Color(0xff9045f7),
                        onPressed: () {
                            print('marker tapped');
                        },
                        ),
                    );
                }
            )
        ),
        CircleLayerOptions(
            circles: CircleMarker( //radius marker
                point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
                borderStrokeWidth: 3.0,
                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                radius: 100 //radius
            )
        )
    ],
),)
```

Comment: Thanks for this,My question is from where I can find the access token ?

Comment: @Hardik1344 You have to use [Mapbox map](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/) in order to use this plugin. Mapbox map is also similar to Google Map. Once you create an account in Mapbox, you will get an access token. Unlike Google map Mapbox doesn't required a billing account get the access token.

Comment: @Thanooshan how can i draw routing using MapBox with FlutterMap library ?

Comment: @Taleb try this plugin and see. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation

Answer (score 5):

You could use google_maps_flutter plugin, here is the code:

```
circles: Set.from([Circle( circleId: CircleId('currentCircle'),
      center: LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude),
      radius: 4000,
          fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.5),
          strokeColor:  Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(0.1),
    ),],),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For an appearance like ios put strokeColor: Colors.blue.shade100.withOpacity(1.0), strokeWidth: 1

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by changing the icon of the Marker

```
mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
    position: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('images/circle.png',),
     ),
);
```

After setting appropriate permission on android/ios, set `trackCameraPosition: true` and `myLocationEnabled: true` on google maps options, after that you can add your image in current location by following code

```
mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
    position: mapController.cameraPosition.target,
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('images/circle.png',),
    ),
);
```

Here is an excellent article which explains all possible things you can do with Google Maps for Flutter (Developers Preview) plugin [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/exploring-google-maps-in-flutter-8a86d3783d24)

Comment: :Thanks,Let me check your answer and article.

Answer (score 1):

There is an opended pull request with this feature at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1136

But Google team has not accepted it because there is a issue with license with whom made the commits. I don't know if this will be merged. There are a lot of pull request accepted, but not integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small suggestion, from the latest changes of [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) you should use this structure for layers:

```
  return FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        initialCenter: LatLng(lat, lng),
      ),
      children: [
        TileLayer(
          urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
        ),
        MarkerLayer(markers: [
          Marker(
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //marker
              point: LatLng(lat, lng),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                onPressed: () {},
              )),

        ]),
        CircleLayer(
            circles: [CircleMarker( 
                point: LatLng(lat, lng),
                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
                borderStrokeWidth: 3.0,
                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                radius: 100 //radius
            )]
        )
      ]);
```

It's almost the same code, but with the proper notation.
It's the same solution Thanooshan proposed, with the correct changes.

Answer (score -1):

Please keep in mind the google maps widget is a developer preview, at version 0.2.  Many things and abilities will likely change over the coming months.

Comment: I think this "answer" is more like a comment than an answer.