# Flutter change radius of drawed circle by buttons

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

As a follow up to the article of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211577/how-to-create-circle-on-current-location-in-flutter) link. I am working on a Flutter Project in which I want to increase the radius of a circle by means of two buttons.

Now I have partly succeeded, but it does not work quite well yet. I don't really know exactly how to explain this, but I will try my best:

What happened is that as soon as I press the minus button it goes a step smaller. If I press the minus button again, it will become a little smaller again. But as soon as I press the plus again, it remains the same size until I pass the number which was highest.

*A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3q5kopEri4) of the problem if its not be clearly explained.*

Maybe someone knows how to handle this?

[image]

**The Code (removed the unnecessary code):**

```
class _AddRayPageState extends State<AddRayPage> {

  List<Marker> myMarker = [];
  final Set<Circle> circle = {};
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  int _n = 8;
  LatLng startLoc = LatLng(52.0907374, 5.1214201);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Toevoegen'),
      ),
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
          markers: Set.from(myMarker),
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: startLoc, zoom: 8),
          circles: circle,
        ),
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 40.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "btnAdd",
                      onPressed: add,
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Text('$_n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0)),
                  Container(
                    width: 40.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "btnMinus",
                      onPressed: minus,
                      child: new Icon(
                        const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void add() {
    setState(() {
      _n++;
    });
    addRadiusToMap(_n);
  }

  void minus() {
    setState(() {
      if (_n != 1) _n--;
    });
    addRadiusToMap(_n);
  }

  void addRadiusToMap(radius) {
    setState(() {
      double reciprocal(double d) => 1000 * d;
      circle.add(Circle(
        circleId: CircleId("1"),
        center: startLoc,
        radius: reciprocal(radius.toDouble()),
      ));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

circle is a Set, a Set doesn't allow repeated objects, in addRadiusToMap you're adding a new Circle object but if there is a previous one with the same fields (7 and 8 already existed) it won't add it, I think the widget GoogleMaps doesn't see a change in the `Set<Circle>` and doesn't update/animate the new Circle, for now try adding `circle.clear()` before adding if the add return false(returns false and the set is not changed)

```
  void add() {
    setState(() {
      _n++;
      addRadiusToMap(_n);
    });
  }

  void minus() {
    if (_n != 1)
      setState(() {
        _n--;
        addRadiusToMap(_n);
      });
  }

  void addRadiusToMap(radius) {
    //No purpose in having 2 setState
    double reciprocal(double d) => 1000 * d;
    circle.clear(); //Maybe clear the set before adding to avoid repeated values
    circle.add(Circle(
      circleId: CircleId("1"),
      center: startLoc,
      radius: reciprocal(radius.toDouble()),
    ));

  }
```

I'm not really sure (I haven't used the Google Maps package) what's the purpose of having a `Set<Circle>` but as far as I understand the code, the Set is not really updated because you already has those values

Comment: It's that simple, Thanks!